# Which from the two given texts is better?

Tags: grammaticality

I had a small argument over my sister's homework. Can you tell me please, which text is better in terms of grammar and narration?
1) Uzbekistan during the spring is one of my most favourite places to be. The first greenery appears in the early days of February. During this season the sun is bright but not as warm as in summer. When it comes to March, the trees begin their blooming. Now and then a warm and gentle rain will fall accompanied by rolling thunder. After it ends, it might cover the sky with a beautiful arc of colourful light. The spring in Uzbekistan is just magnificent.
2) One of the most important places which I prefer in Uzbekistan become during spring. Every year the trees begin to blooming in the beginning of March. During the spring there are gentle rain falls with accompanying thunderstorms. After ending there is might be beautiful rainbow in the sky. In Uzbekistan the spring is just magnificent.
If you can, for both, please mention what are the mistakes and why it is wrong.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Neither is good English. The second example is worse. Don't be mean to your sister.

Comment: Great question. To improve format, and make for easier reading, divide into paragraphs. You might have to push the space bar twice. Check on the preview below to see what works, i.e. how many pushes it takes to make it look good. You can still edit it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention. The first version is the one that my sister wrote and the second one is how her "teacher" corrected it.

Comment: I'm glad I didn't know that. I might have been afraid to correct the teacher yet there were a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beautiful description. I have never been in Uzbekistan but I have often seen this kind of weather in my home county in Ontario, Canada. Our spring comes two or three months later than in Uzbekistan. I will critique both versions of this paragraph. The first one is by far the best but contains a few errors.

**First Version**

I will copy the entire text, and bold-face the mistakes for discussion.

> Uzbekistan during the spring is one of my most favourite places to be.
>   The first greenery appears in the early days of February. During this
>   season the sun is bright but not as warm as in summer. **When it comes
>   to March, the trees begin their blooming.**

I'm not sure why but we don't say it that way. Here are two different ways to say this in English:

1. When March comes, the trees start blooming.
2. In March the trees bloom.

You can play around with the wording, e.g.:

- When March comes the trees begin to bloom.
- Come March, the trees begin to bloom.

To say "Come March..." or "Come Saturday..." or "When it comes time to.." merely means "When March arrives..." or "When Saturday arrives..." or "when it's time to..." It's a rather idiomatic way of speaking and might not be so easy for English Language Learners. However, if you move to a land of native English-speakers you will hear it. Hence I include it here.

> Now and then a warm and gentle **rain will fall** accompanied by rolling thunder.

That is grammatically correct and we may sometimes say it that way. However, when we are describing a season like this in English, normally we say:

> Now and then a gentle rains falls accompanied by rolling thunder.

Again, I'm not sure why but it is the way we speak. We don't say "rain will fall," just "rain falls." Normally, we say "rain will fall" when we describe the scientific cycle of evaporation and condescension that causes rain.

> **After it ends**,

That is grammatically correct but it sounds clumsy. We generally say something like:

- Afterwards...
- When the shower/rain is over...

> **it might cover the sky with a beautiful arc of colourful light**.

To understand your meaning for this, I had to read Version 2. You mean a rainbow arcing across the sky.

> **The spring** in Uzbekistan is just magnificent.

Again, this is grammatically correct but it is not the way we speak. We don't use an article in front of *spring* for this kind of sentence. We say:

> Spring in Uzbekistan is just magnificent.

For an ELL discussion on leaving out the article for some nouns, see [Omission of articles in phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244622/omission-of-articles-in-phrases/244628#244628).

I am not sure about using the word "just." Maybe it is okay, or maybe it should be omitted. In my mother-tongue we use it but I think my friends who have all their lives spoken only English might not. They would put a lot of feeling in the word "magnificent" and say:

> Spring in Uzbekistan is magnificent.

**Second Version**

I will continue with the same method of highlighting errors with bold-face for discussion.

> **One of the most important places which I prefer in Uzbekistan become during spring.**

I have to read Version 1 to understand the meaning of this.

> Every year the trees **begin to blooming** in the beginning of March.

This is very good but not grammatically correct. The correct way is either:

1. begin to bloom, OR
2. begin blooming.

You cannot use "to" with a word that ends in "ing."

> During the spring **there are gentle rain falls** with accompanying
>   thunderstorms.

This is grammatically correct except "rainfalls" is one word. I think that sentence is cute or quaint: There are gentle rainfalls accompanied by thunderstorms.

Okay, I changed a few words around to make it smoother. The original is fine except for the split word. However, it is more common to say "showers" instead of "rainfalls."

Also, *thunderstorm* sounds rather incongruent to accompany "gentle rainfall" or "gentle shower." For this reason, I prefer "rolling thunder" of Version 1. Another common description of thunder that is not a violent storm is "rumbling thunder."

> **After ending there is might be** beautiful rainbow in the sky.

This is wrong. I will divide it into two parts:

- After ending
- is might be

***After ending...***

We have to say what is ending. Since the previous part was about gentle rains and rolling thunder, it is reasonable to think this means when the showers end. We can say:

> After the rainfall ends...

***...is might be...***

The words "is might be" never go together in a row like that. We cannot say: There is might be...

Here are two things we can say:

1. There is...
2. There might be...

We might rewrite your sentence like this:

> After the rainfall (or shower) ends, there might be a beautiful
>   rainbow in the sky.

Please note that I inserted the indefinite article "a." An article is needed in front of *rainbow* in that sentence because it's just one of many rainbows that appear in the sky.

> In Uzbekistan **the** spring is **just** magnificent.

This sentence is grammatically correct but somewhat clumsy. As discussed for Version 1, we do not put an article in front of *spring* when used like this. As also discussed, the word "just" is probably not needed. The best way to say it is:

> Spring in Uzbekistan is magnificent.

*Magnificent* is such a magnificent word, so superlative, like an apple trees in all its glory of pink blossoms against a clear blue sky, that no modifiers are needed. I don't know a better way of saying it but that is the impression I get from listening to English-speakers speak.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect that someone will actually write about the mistakes. Thank you very much, that helped a lot. 

Comment: You asked for help with the mistakes. I found this question when reviewing stuff. I liked it so much I stopped the other stuff to answer it. Glad my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The first text is better. It may not be grammatically perfect, but it is very close and much better than the second text.

Comment: However, "a beautiful arc of colourful light" should be called a rainbow.